# Android issue install the same app to multiple accounts on a device

Tags: android, installation, google-play, apk, uninstallation

I have a two accounts which are signed in different gmail addressess on a device.In *First account* install app via Play Market then get into *Second account* and tried to install the same app.As you guess app is installed without downloading.It works ok, but go to back *First account* and uninstall app via play market and install again. The same stuff, it is installed without downloading. And app is gonna crash, because app couldn't download my indeed libs files. Does anyone have idea what kinda approach google has in this situation? Please give me completly ideas?